# Generate PDF file with Zend Framework 2

Tags: pdf-generation, zend-framework2

I'm started to learn ZF2 right now and notice that there's no "Zend_Pdf" or similar on zend framework 2...

How can I create pdf on this version of the framework?

Anyone knows a good tutorial?

Comment: You don't need to use Zend here - plenty of other ways to create a PDF. Take a look at FPDF for example, or for something a bit more flexible, JasperServer over SOAP.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Zend Framework 2 has moved many of the old Zend Framework libraries out of the main core and created modules instead. Zend_Pdf is one of the libraries that was moved to a module. You can find them all in the [Zend Framework repository on GitHub](https://github.com/zendframework).

You need the [ZendPdf package](https://github.com/zendframework/ZendPdf), just follow the instructions on the page. Documentation is not ready yet simply because it's not a core module. Documentation will probably follow as soon as all bugs are worked out with the core stuff.

Also see the [Zend Framework package repository](http://packages.zendframework.com/).

Comment: Great! Thanks for the answer! ZendPdf remains the same as old Zend_Pdf? Why there's no references to ZendPdf on the documentation?

Comment: Simply because it's not a core module. Documentation will probably follow as soon as all bugs are worked out with the core stuff

Comment: @Sam Thanks for the info. I edited it into my answer, I hope you don't mind.

Comment: Is zendPdf documentation is avaliable now.If it is.Please provide me the link to create pdf in zf2.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to generate a PDF in ZF2 environment, there is [a brief tutorial how to do that with PD4ML](http://pd4ml.com/cookbook/pd4ml_and_zend_framework_2.htm). The approach does not require to program a PDF layout (like createPdfDocument(), startParagraph(), addImage() etc). It just converts an existent rendered view (HTML + CSS + SVG + images) to PDF or optionally to RTF.

Comment: It is a paid and quite expensive software... There are other free possibilities for PHP like [mpdf](http://www.mpdf1.com).

Answer (score 0):

If you need a module that allow easy to thumbnail, snapshot or PDF generation from a url or a html you can take a look to [MvlabsSnappy](https://github.com/mvlabs/MvlabsSnappy) based on Snappy PHP (5.3+) wrapper for the **wkhtmltopdf & wkhtmltoimage** conversion utility.