# How to use ZendPdf\Pdf in Zend Framework 2

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-framework2

I am trying to use ZendPdf in Zend Framework. I am building upon the skeleton application. I have used `composer.phar` to get the required packages for ZendPdf and all the files are now under a directory called `zendpdf` in the same directory as the directory `zendframwork` in `vendor` so I assume that the package update worked.

Here is my IndexController.php

```
<?php

namespace Application\Controller;

use Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractActionController;
use Zend\View\Model\ViewModel;
use Zend\Json\Json;

class IndexController extends AbstractActionController
{
        public function indexAction()
        { 


                    $fileName = 'foo.pdf';
                    $pdf = \ZendPdf\Pdf::load($fileName);   


                    // Some JSON stuff etc
                    // …
        }   
}
```

I get the following error:

```
Fatal error: Class 'ZendPdf\Pdf' not found in /mnt/host-home/websites/mywebsite.com/module/Application/src/Application/Controller/IndexController.php on line 16
```

I am still trying to get my head around namespaces etc. Any help is appreciated.

EDIT:

I know that the PDF functionality is not included with ZF2, which is why I have used composer.phar to get it. What I would really like to know is how to I instantiate the ZendPDF class?

Comment: There is no longer Pdf in ZF2. See this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12673089/generate-pdf-file-with-zend-framework-2)

Comment: Yes I understand that. Which is why I have downloaded the package using `composer.phar`. My question is how do I instantiate the class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no class `Pdf` in `ZendPdf`, I think you probably meant `PdfDocument`:

```
\ZendPdf\PdfDocument::load($fileName);
```

Since you said you're new to namespaces, I'd recommend using the `use` command to help make your code a bit more readable. If you were to add:

```
use ZendPdf\PdfDocument;
```

to the top of your class, PHP then knows that `PdfDocument` refers to `\ZendPdf\PdfDocument`, so you can then just do:

```
PdfDocument::load($fileName);
```

in your controller action.

Answer (score 1):

Came here with the same error; I'd solved this way:

A. If downloaded from the composer, go to step C. For manual downloads, create a "zendpdf" folder on   vendor\zendframework:

example:
C:\mywww\zf2\vendor\zendframework\zendpdf

B. Copy the [masterzip](https://github.com/zendframework/ZendPdf/archive/master.zip) contents (Library folder, test folder, composer.json, etc) on the new "zendpdf" folder.

C. Edit the StandardAutoloader.php from:

C:\mywww\zf2\vendor\zendframework\zendframework\library\Zend\Loader\StandardAutoloader.php

```
    .
    .
    .
    foreach ($options as $type => $pairs) {
switch ($type) {                
    case self::AUTOREGISTER_ZF:                    
        if ($pairs) {
            $this->registerNamespace('Zend', dirname(__DIR__));
            $this->registerNamespace('ZendXml', dirname(dirname((__DIR__))) . '/ZendXml');
            $this->registerNamespace('ZendPdf', dirname(dirname((__DIR__))) . '/ZendPdf');  //add this line.                      
        }
        break;
    .
    .
    .
```

That's all; now we can use the Pdf functions:

```
    use ZendPdf\PdfDocument; //dont' forget to add this at start   ;)
    $pdf1 = new PdfDocument(); // Create a new PDF document
    //$fileName = 'test.pdf';
    //$pdf2 = Zend_Pdf::load($fileName);// Load a PDF document from a file
    //$pdf3 = Zend_Pdf::parse($pdfString);// Load a PDF document from a string
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are using ZendPdf\pdf::load(). This has been modified in zf2 v>2.0 to be ZendPdf\PdfDocument::load().
Hope this solves the problem.